# iOS Development Environment Setup Questions

Tags: ios, sdk

I am new to iOS SDK environment setup. I'd appreciate it if someone help me with the following questions:

1. How do I get a complete list of Apple devices (iPhone, iPad, MacBook Pro and etc) that can be setup with iOS SDK enviornments?
2. Are there iOS SDK environment Setup Guides?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Well you just have to download XCode and that's pretty much it (Only if you own a Mac of course).

Once you open XCode and write an app you'll have a list of Simulator devices appear in the top left corner next to the run button, you can choose any of them and press run and that'll run the simulator.

Comment: Thanks so much! Ahmed.
I am a tester who needs to set up the iOS SDK environments. How can I achieve the goal of figuring out what those Apple devices are?

I've found Xcode 10.1 download here. How should I proceed from a non developer's position?
https://developer.apple.com/download/

Comment: Hi Ahmed, Maybe I can write a simple app, could you show me your app that shows a list of Simulator devices if possible? Thanks.

Comment: This is for work, I will try to download Xcode 10.1 on my personal MacBook Pro at home before I can convince them to buy one for work.

Comment: Just download XCode from the app store and for a starter I recommend you start with the tutorials found at https://www.raywenderlich.com/ios

Maybe start with this one : https://www.raywenderlich.com/5993-your-first-ios-app

Good luck on making that jump and I assure you that iOS is a lot of fun and you'll always have something to learn yet it's very easy to start

Comment: Thanks a million, Ahmed. My MacBook Pro should be sufficient. Right?

Comment: Which one (MacBook, MacBook Pro or MacBook Air) for iOS SDK that develops apps that talk to our credit card reader do you recommend ? Thanks.

Comment: A MacBook Pro later than 2011 (Anything that has the latest OS) will do and that's pretty much all you need, having an iPhone would help too in some cases

Comment: Great. Thanks again, Ahmed. I will work on learning to write my first app.